# Происхождение фамилии Зленская

Tags: ономастика

Может быть у кого-нибудь есть догадки насчет происхождения фамилии Зленская? Мои родственники считают, что происхождение — польское, но найти мою фамилию среди польских не удалось.

Answer (score 1):

Да, скорее всего - польская. По форме. Но этимология затуманена. Имена собственные (топонимы в основном) в форме, например, Zliensky встречаются в разных славянских языках: словацком, чешском, хорватском, основа, возможно, как-то связана с чем-то зеленым. Но такая этимология для польского сомнительна по фонетическим причинам.

Вот единственное, что нашел

> U.S. Naturalization Record Indexes, 1791-1992 (Indexed in World
>   Archives Project) Citizenship & Naturalization Records View Image
>   Name:     John Zlensky Birth:     15 Apr 1894 - Poland Civil:     15 Sep 1944
>   Residence:    Illinois, Indiana, Wisconsin, Iowa Residence:   Wisconsin

http://search.ancestry.co.uk/cgi-bin/sse.dll?gl=40&rank=1&new=1&so=3&MSAV=0&msT=1&gss=genfact&gsln=Zlensky&uidh=000&cp=101&cpxt=1

Из этой записи следует, что некий Джон Зленский (Zlensky), родившийся в 1894 г. и имевший гражданство Польши, натурализован в США в 1944 г.

Кроме того, эта фамилия в такой же форме встречается базах жителей Великобритании.

Этот факт, наряду с отсутствием разумного объяснения польской этимологии и еще некоторыми косвенными признаками, позволяет предположить, что носителями фамилии могли быть польские евреи. Что, впрочем, не исключает того, что фамилия сама по себе - польская.

Мне хорошо знакома польская (и еврейская) фамилия Злинский. Но тут тоже все напутано, поскольку она может быть и чешской, а то и русской - по соответствующим топонимам. Аналогично - Зеленский.

Но это всё догадки.

На всякий случай. Есть еще несколько фантастических "объяснений" типа
http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%97%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9
Я совершенно не доверяю подобным сайтам (там просто "с потолка" подставляют города, веси, национальности и годы), поэтому не рассматриваю всерьез. Тем более, что "версия" эта не несет этимологического объяснения.

Answer (score 1):

Широко известны фамилии Зленко, Зеленский.

Есть версия, которая указывает на корень ***зелен*** и его вариант ***злен***. Зелень, зелёный. Такое распространённое в юго-западных районах страны прозвище означало не что иное, как *молодой*. По смыслу это тоже, что и незрелый, бледный, неопытный.